# Installing sbt on mac osx

Tags: macos, sbt

I installed SBT on my mac OSX via

```
brew install sbt
```

command and also alternatively installed it manually.

But, when I run for example

```
sbt run MY_PROJECT
```

I get `"java.io.IOException: Permission denied"` but when I run it via `"sudo"` everything work.

Also Intellij Idea idea does not import my SBT project because of mentioned error.

I searched a lot but nothing found.

Comment: Installing `sbt` manually and with **homebrew** as well is a recipe for disaster. Stick to one or the other! I suggest you remove your manual installation and stick with the simple **homebrew** one, and then ensure that you are running `/usr/local/bin/sbt` which is the **homebrew** version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to change the permissions in your sbt.

```
sudo chmod o+x /usr/local/sbt/sbt /usr/local/sbt/sbt-launch.jar
```

Try this. It looks like you installed sbt via sudo user. Now sbt is in the sudo directory. You can also try to do brew install sbt without sudo. And uninstall the sbt installed in your sudo directory.

Comment: i did not install sbt by root. i tried your command but did not work.